# Tomcat9 / Java11 upgrade: truncating body of POST?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I recently updated a Debian server from Java 8 / Tomcat 8 to Java 11 / Tomcat 9. I have another server that works fine with 11/9 and the server I just updated worked fine with 8/8.

But the updated server seems to consistently truncate the body of POST requests as seen inside a test servlet. Why is this happening?

Test servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    System.out.println("got POST");
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = httpRequest.getReader();
        String line = null;
        int len = 0;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            len += line.length();
        }
        System.out.println("total post body size: " + len);
        PrintWriter out = httpResponse.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello Post World ");
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Postman console says 'Content-Length: 101200'. With shorter content (100's of bytes), it works fine. The servlet doesn't throw any errors - the above logs '[2020-07-29 15:59:56] [info] total post body size: 16067' and the client gets a proper response. Is this something related to chunking and changes in Java 11 and/or Tomcat 9?

Comment: in your server.xml, is there some limiting parameter being used.  e.g. in the HTTP connector, is maxPostSize being set?

Comment: Is the content actually text or binary data?

Comment: Try logging the `Content-Length` header in your server-side code to see if it agrees with with Postman is sending.

Answer (score 0):

The OP didn't mention whether the connections are HTTP or HTTPS.  This is a very late reply, probably @GregT has long since solved the problem, still for anyone else who lands here, here's what I dug out today when diagnosing a truncated-POST request problem that happens on HTTPS connections with TLS 1.3 but never on HTTP connections.

Apache Tomcat version 9.0.31 has/had a problem with reading data from SSL/TLS connections that happens sporadically depending on the exact timing. Plain old HTTP works fine.  The solution is to upgrade to 9.0.32 or later. Also see:

[Spring endpoint receives truncated body for larger http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190403/spring-endpoint-receives-truncated-body-for-larger-http-requests)

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64202

Comment: Thank you for replying. It was HTTPS. I eventually found a report of this problem as you described it and avoided 9.0.31 until it was fixed. In my case it happened 100% of the time, not sporadic at all. Cheers!